# Issue in constantly updating sensor data in website received from arduino uno

Tags: javascript, php, html, arduino-uno, esp8266

I am new to Arduino uno. My task is to send Ir sensor data to web application. I used `AT+CIPSEND` command to send data to web application. I am using xampp control panel to create server on my pc But issue is that value which I getting from php is throwing an error unidentified index value. From my point of view, there might be latency issue. I tried using `setInterval()` to make ajax call in every 1 sec but still issue is same.

**Arduino code**

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    #define RX 10
    #define TX 11
    String AP = "Tenda_2704A8";       // CHANGE ME
    String PASS = "8108805837"; // CHANGE ME
    String HOST = "192.168.0.104";
    String PORT = "80";
    String Data;
    int countTrueCommand;
    int countTimeCommand;
    boolean found = false;

    int LED = 13; // Use the onboard Uno LED
    int isObstaclePin = 7;  // This is our input pin
    int isObstacle = HIGH;  // HIGH MEANS NO OBSTACLE


    SoftwareSerial esp8266(RX, TX);


    void setup() {
      pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(isObstaclePin, INPUT);
      Serial.begin(9600);
      esp8266.begin(115200);
      sendCommand("AT", 5, "OK");
      sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=1", 5, "OK");
      sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=\"" + AP + "\",\"" + PASS + "\"", 20, "OK");
      sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1",5,"OK");  


    }
    void loop() {

      String output;

      isObstacle = digitalRead(isObstaclePin);
      if (isObstacle == LOW)
      { 
        output = "obstacle";
        Serial.println("OBSTACLE!!, OBSTACLE!!");
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
      }
      else
      { 
        output = "clear";
        Serial.println("clear");
        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
      }



      Data = "GET project/ajax/arduino.php?value=2";
      sendCommand("AT+CIPSTART=0,\"TCP\",\""+ HOST +"\","+ PORT,5,"OK");
      sendCommand("AT+CIPSEND=0," +String(Data.length()+4),4,">");
      Serial.println(Data);delay(100);countTrueCommand++;
      sendCommand("AT+CIPCLOSE=0",5,"OK");



    }


    void sendCommand(String command, int maxTime, char readReplay[]) {
      Serial.print(countTrueCommand);
      Serial.print(". at command => ");
      Serial.print(command);
      Serial.print(" ");
      while (countTimeCommand < (maxTime * 1))
      {
        esp8266.println(command);//at+cipsend
        if (esp8266.find(readReplay)) //ok
        {
          found = true;
          break;
        }

        countTimeCommand++;
      }

      if (found == true)
      {
        Serial.println("Yes");
        countTrueCommand++;
        countTimeCommand = 0;
      }

      if (found == false)
      {
        Serial.println("Fail");
        countTrueCommand = 0;
        countTimeCommand = 0;
      }

      found = false;
    }
```

**Arduino.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function fetchdata(){
                $.ajax({
                url:"arduino.php",
                success:function(response){
                    $("#value").text(response);
                }

                });
            }
            setInterval(fetchdata,100);

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id = "value"></h1>

</body>
</html>
```

**arduino.php**

```
<?php
/*$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","arduino");
if(!$conn){
    die("connectionfailed".mysqli_error());
}*/

$val = $_GET['value'];

echo $val;

//$sql = "INSERT INTO `arduino` (value) VALUES ('".$_GET['value']."')";

//mysqli_query($conn,$sql);


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your code. Your code is only printing the value it receives from the arduino. You will need to store the data you receive from the arduino so you return it when needed. What you should do is something like

```
if(isset($_GET["value"]))
{
//save the data somewhere
}
else{
//fetch saved data and echo it
}
```

Comment: I already had used isset($_GET["value ") but it still throwing me an error unidentified index "value".

Comment: Did you get the error at the same line because you shouldn't. can you post that code? Remember to only use `$_GET["value"]` inside the if